# Using procs/lambdas with arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, scope, proc

### Edited to include SSCE

I have a Proc object which I add to a Hash with other Procs:

```
ten_percent_discount_over_sixty = Proc.new {
  cart.each { |item| cart_total += item.price }

  if cart_total >= 60.00
    cart_total =- cart_total * 0.1
  end
}
```

As you can see there is a `cart` array which contains `items`. I can't however get my `cart` instance variable into the scope of this proc. So later when I iterate through all of these `rules` in another method, I get `undefined variable` errors.

The point of doing this is that I have various promotional rules (functions) that need to be run on this cart object. It's possible there's a better way to store `rules` that can be applied iteratively to a objects instance variable.

---

I have `checkout` object which contains a cart (an array) of `item` objects; `items` have the attributes: `code`, `price` and `name`.

Next I have a `Promotion` object which holds a hash of `promotional rules`. This hash contains `Proc` objects that hold these rules (which are functions that each run on the cart object changing the final price of the cart). Rules maybe added and removed by calling a method and with the name as an argument.

The problem I am having is when I iterate through the hash of `promotional rules`. I don't know how to get the `cart` object into the scope of those `Proc` objects in order to run the functions contained in those `Proc` objects, changing the `cart` state.

1. Do I pass in the cart object when creating the Proc/lambda?
2. Create a cart instance variable in the `Promotion` object and set/get it?
3. Somehow pass in the cart variable within the `checkout` object?
4. I'm over-thinking or approaching the problem in an incorrect manner?

The full code is quite long so I'll post a `gist` below:

https://gist.github.com/3163127

Comment: Please, try reducing this to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It'll be a lot easier for us to help you this way.

Comment: wow, you have a lot of side-effects in this code, you'll have a hard time (I'd have, at least) reasoning about its correctness. As a rule of thumb, minimize state and use methods/function as purely as possible (with inputs/output in arguments/return_value, no with instance variable updates).

Comment: I'll work on it. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rule procs must accept cart as an argument, act on it, and return modified cart.

```
cart = {total: 100}

rules = {ten_percent_discount: lambda{|c| c[:total] *= 0.9; c },
  five_percent_discount: lambda{|c| c[:total] *= 0.95; c}}

rules.each do |name, rule|
  cart = rule.call cart.dup
end

cart # => {:total=>85.5}
```

Comment: It seems cleaner to me if the caller `dup`s cart, just in case someone writing a rule forgot to do it themselves.